# How can I make my space background move down as if I'm in a spaceship travelling through space?

Tags: c++, 2d, codeblocks, bgi

So far I've gotten my program to display a bunch of pixels in varying colours that appear randomly on a screen. I was wondering if it is possible to have the pixels move downward, kind of like you're moving forward in space in a spaceship. This is my program so far, it's very simplistic but does what I need it to.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    int i, x, y;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TC\\BGI");
    initwindow(1200, 768);

      /* color 500 random pixels on screen */
   for(i=0; i<=125; i++) {
       x=rand()%getmaxx();
          y=rand()%getmaxy();
          putpixel(x,y,1);
      }

      for(i=0; i<=125; i++) {
       x=rand()%getmaxx();
          y=rand()%getmaxy();
          putpixel(x,y,2);
      }

      for(i=0; i<=125; i++) {
       x=rand()%getmaxx();
          y=rand()%getmaxy();
          putpixel(x,y,3);
      }

      for(i=0; i<=125; i++) {
       x=rand()%getmaxx();
          y=rand()%getmaxy();
          putpixel(x,y,4);
      }

      for(i=0; i<=125; i++) {
       x=rand()%getmaxx();
          y=rand()%getmaxy();
          putpixel(x,y,5);
      }

      for(i=0; i<=125; i++) {
       x=rand()%getmaxx();
          y=rand()%getmaxy();
          putpixel(x,y,6);
      }

      for(i=0; i<=125; i++) {
       x=rand()%getmaxx();
          y=rand()%getmaxy();
          putpixel(x,y,7);
      }

      for(i=0; i<=125; i++) {
       x=rand()%getmaxx();
          y=rand()%getmaxy();
          putpixel(x,y,8);
      }

      for(i=0; i<=125; i++) {
       x=rand()%getmaxx();
          y=rand()%getmaxy();
          putpixel(x,y,9);
      }
      for(i=0; i<=125; i++) {
       x=rand()%getmaxx();
          y=rand()%getmaxy();
          putpixel(x,y,9);
      }
      for(i=0; i<=125; i++) {
       x=rand()%getmaxx();
          y=rand()%getmaxy();
          putpixel(x,y,10);
      }
      for(i=0; i<=125; i++) {
       x=rand()%getmaxx();
          y=rand()%getmaxy();
          putpixel(x,y,11);
      }
      for(i=0; i<=125; i++) {
       x=rand()%getmaxx();
          y=rand()%getmaxy();
          putpixel(x,y,12);
      }
      for(i=0; i<=125; i++) {
       x=rand()%getmaxx();
          y=rand()%getmaxy();
          putpixel(x,y,13);
      }
      for(i=0; i<=100; i++) {
       x=rand()%getmaxx();
          y=rand()%getmaxy();
          putpixel(x,y,14);
      }

      for(i=0; i<=900; i++) {
       x=rand()%getmaxx();
          y=rand()%getmaxy();
          putpixel(x,y,15);
      }

    getch();
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Store the coordinate for each pixel, use a timer and then update the y position for each pixel?

Comment: By the way, this looks like `c` not `c++` =)

Comment: _off-topic_: you should consider making a function to avoid the dozen similar `for` loops in `main`

Comment: you know you could do 2 nested for loops instead of 16 times copy paste the same code  ...  Add offset based on your ship position/speed and wrap around screen edges. Also you need `seed` and some timing main loop to allow animation. What OS is this (BGI is MS-DOS but codeblock is not so you got most likely emulator somewhere (either BGI or MS-DOS)) ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate your background image just once then display it multiple times with a screen clear and transformation between.

```
struct COORD {
  unsigned short x;
  unsigned short y;
};
COORD stars[STAR_COUNT];

for(int star = 0; STAR_COUNT > star; ++star)
{
  stars[star].x = rand() % SCREEN_WIDTH;
  stars[star].y = rand() % SCREEN_HEIGHT;
}
```

and then perhaps for each frame do something like:

```
for(int star = 0; STAR_COUNT > star; ++star)
{
  --stars[star].x;
  --stars[nstar].y;
}
```

Comment: there are no frames in the OP source code ... and from level of coding the author is complete rookie so even if this is not a bad solution it will be most likely not comprehended by the target audience

Comment: there are no frames in the OP source code (nor any control/continuous loop) ... and from level of coding the author is complete rookie so even if this is not a bad solution it will be most likely not comprehended by the target audience. Also using seed and offset you do not need to remember the stars at all...